# C programming, infinite loop stops unexpectedly

Tags: c, embedded, host

I have been working on the c codes for my boost converter project. As soon as the embedded codes uploaded to the ilmatto (microprocessor), the voltage is stabilised to initial value of Vwanted, which in my case is 4.

But, the problem appears when I send a value replacing Vwanted using a host program, the value of Vwanted does replaced, but the value of output voltage maintains at 4, which is the value of Vwanted before being replaced.

I tried to printf the value of Vwanted, to check whether the replacement successful, and it did!

So, I suspect that initially the inner for(;;) runs, but then after the replacement value of Vwanted, the program never goes to the inner for(;;) again. This is proved when I used putty, and uart cable to observe the return data. It does printing "." initially, without me entering a new value of Vwanted. But later when a new value of Vwanted is entered, the putty does not printing anything.

If this was true, it means that the outer for(;;) loop seems to be not working.

Please help me!!!

Here I include the main function in my embedded.c program,

```
int main(void)
{   
    uint16_t cnt =0;

    int duty_value = 210;
    char cmd[BUFFSIZE];
    //char tail[BUFFSIZE];
    int prm;
    int res;

    init_stdio2uart0();
    init_pwm();
    init_adc();

    double Vwanted = 4; //initialise voltage
    double *ptr = &Vwanted;
    //pwm_duty(duty_value);

    double v_out;
    double Verror;

    /* set LED pin as an output */
    DDRB |= _BV(PINB7);

    printf("\r\nIlMatto Coms READY!\r\n");

    for(;;)
    {   

        /* Following idea from jwaf1g14*/
        for(;;) 
        {       

            v_out = v_load()/0.150;

            Verror = Vwanted - v_out;
            printf(".");

            if (Verror < 0)
            {
                if (Verror < -4)
                {
                    duty_value = duty_value - 2;
                    pwm_duty(duty_value); /* Limited by PWM_DUTY_MAX */
                }
                else if (Verror > -4)
                {
                    duty_value = duty_value - 1;
                    pwm_duty(duty_value); /* Limited by PWM_DUTY_MAX */
                }
            }
            else if (Verror > 0)
            {
                if (Verror > 4)
                {
                    duty_value = duty_value + 2;
                    pwm_duty(duty_value); /* Limited by PWM_DUTY_MAX */
                }
                else if (Verror < 4)
                {
                    duty_value = duty_value + 1;
                    pwm_duty(duty_value); /* Limited by PWM_DUTY_MAX */
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pwm_duty(duty_value);    /* Limited by PWM_DUTY_MAX */
            }

            if(kbhit()) // Check if there is an input available
            {
                res = scanf("%s %u", cmd, &prm);

                printf("%04d: CMD was: \"%s\" with %d (%d)\r\n", cnt, cmd, prm, res);

                break;
             } 

        //printf( " Vout -->  %5.3f V\r\n", v_out );

    }/*End of inner forever loop*/

    if ( res !=2 )/* Error! */ 
        {   
            printf("Your serial connection is broken!!!");
            //scanf("%*s");  /* Clear input buffer */
            //fflush(stdin);


        } 
    else
        {   
            if ( prm > 12 || prm < 1)
            {
                printf("The setpoint entered cannot be achieved");

                /* Set pin B7 high */
                PORTB |= _BV(PINB7);
                _delay_ms(100);
                /* Set pin B7 low */
                PORTB &= ~_BV(PINB7);
                _delay_ms(900);
            }
            else if ( prm < 12 && prm > 1)
            {

                *ptr = (double)prm;
                printf("Vset is %f,", Vwanted);

                //printf("Hello");
            }

        }


    }/*End of outer forever loop*/

    return 0;

}/*End of main loop*/
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior here `fflush(stdin);`. `fflush()` is for output buffers only.

Comment: That was added as I tried to solve my problem. It didnt do much actually. I forgot to delete that code statement afterward.

Comment: but still without fflush(stdin);  the problem still occurs

Comment: check Katie's answer...

Comment: Also, your braces don't line up. Always a bad sign.

Comment: Please explain Lee Daniel Crocker

Comment: Daniel is telling you that your indentation is not ok. Try to add v_load fucntion code. Maybe could be there the problem.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant to your problem, but you test `if (prm > 12 || prm < 1)` and you test `if (prm < 12 && prm > 1)` but you have overlooked `if (prm == 12 || prm == 1)` and so should one of your two statements include equality tests?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop ends with `return Vwanted;` which will return from the main function, ending your program. Eliminating that line will allow your outer loop to continue. I suspect you don't intend to return anything from this function.

Comment: It was added as I suspected the new value of Vwanted is not replaced. It was random guess anyway. Even without that, the problem still persists.

Comment: @zuladli : Then remove it from the code in the question!